# TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha 3 deleting my .tex files

Tags: texniccenter, filesystem-access

I am using TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha 3, and I'm experiencing a weird problem where it seems to be deleting my `.tex` files occasionally. I'm not sure this is the best place to ask, but I wasn't sure where else to ask. I've also sugmitted a report about this on the sourceforge project page. Also, I realize it's an Alpha version so bug are to be expected.

So, occasionally when TeXnicCenter tries to save the currently active file, I get a small popup error window with the following message:

```
Cannot save the file

C:\%path%\%file%.tex

Cannot create a file that already exists.
```

where `%path%` and `%file%` are the path and filename of the file currently being edited.

Again, this happens only during some file saves, not all, and since a file save occurs whenever I build, and also whenever autosave dictates, I will occasionally get this message at the beginning of a build, in which case the build fails, and also it will occasionally pop up out of nowhere because Autosave has tried to save and failed.

The details of the what happens are as follows:

- A save is attemped by build or autosave
- Above-mentioned error window pops up
- I press ok
- If I look in my working directory now, the file is missing, meaning the only copy is the one open in the TeXnicCenter GUI (Scary!! What if my computer crashes now? My file's lost.)
- If I try to build again, I get a second error saying `File %path%%name% could not be found`
- I can then manually save the file via <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> and build will then succeed.

I haven't been able to figure out if there is a correlation with other programs being open when this happens, and it is sporadic and not unique to any particular project, so it is not feasible to provide a MWE to reproduce it.

I am using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, and MikTeX 2.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experimenting, I discovered that this problem only seems to happen when Windows Live Mesh is open. I've been using it to keep my work folder synced between two computers. Not sure if this is Mesh or TXC misbehaving. Even though I never had this problem with TXC 1, my inclination is still to blame it on the MS product.

If anyone else has encountered the same problem, there's a report thread about it on Sourceforge [here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3298029&group_id=36323&atid=479426).

Comment: Further update: I'm now experiencing the same problem with TXC 1. I used Windows Live Sync for a long time before being forced to upgrade to Mesh, and I never had this issue with Sync, so I now suspect the fault lies with Mesh and how it handles files. I'll post again if I find out anything new.

Comment: Yet another quick update: in the Sourceforge report thread I linked to, another user has now reported the same behaviour when running Windows Live Mesh. No further info yet on who's to blame.